# For how much time i will be prevented form asking questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Recently I was blocked out form questioning on askubuntu because of too much downvoted questions, now the question is I have made enough rep progress after that how much time I have to wait to ask questions??

Comment: Did you read the link in the ban message? The process is entirely automatic, and will be lifted automatically. All you can do is improve your questions, write good answers, and don't ask bad questions.

Comment: thanx seth but can you make an answer for it??